# Oracle instant client for .net on 64 bit windows server 2008

Tags: .net, oracle, windows-server-2008

I installed [Oracle 11g ODAC 11.1.0.6.21 with Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio](http://www.oracle.com/technology/software/tech/windows/odpnet/index.html) and built my app. I installed [Oracle 11g ODAC 11.1.0.6.21 with Xcopy Deployment](http://www.oracle.com/technology/software/tech/windows/odpnet/index.html) on the 32 bit server and it runs great. But now I need to install on a 64 bit server.

Where can one find the 64 bit Oracle 11g ODAC?

The Oracle client is installed on the 64 bit server is there anyway to use the existing install with .net?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forum Discussion : http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=3239391

A quick read indicates that there may be a patch available to get ODAC x64 for 11g.